# eclipse any way to cycle through the 'errors' listed under the 'problems view' ?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, eclipse

If you do a <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>G</kbd> let's say on a method. You get all the occurrences where that methods is being used, and you see that list in the 'Search' view. Pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>,</kbd> cycles through each one of them, placing the particular file in the editor area ( and closing it if you moved to next file).

Is there any way to do similar navigation for errors under the 'problems view'?